# How to resolve this nfs problem?

Tags: nfs

On syslog i see

```
sm-notify[963]: DNS resolution of hpux.verde.local failed; retrying later
```

hpux.verde.local was an old testserver,now the net has another name and this server didn't exist.
I search on /etc/ /var/lib/nfs and i can't see any reference to hpux.verde.local
How to solve?

Comment: Are you using something like NIS?  It could be that the server is sending you an auto.* that includes things to mount, try `yptest` and/or `ypcat auto.master` if you are and those should give you some ideas of things it is telling you to mount.  Those would have to be fixed on the server if they're the source of the old name

Comment: No nis ypcat return error domain not set,and i not set because i don't use nis

Comment: Do you see a file named hpux.verde.local in the /var/lib/nfs/sm.bak directory?

Comment: yes i see,i try to remove

Comment: Now must work ,if add as answer i will vote your comment

Comment: FYI, on `CentOS 7` it's under `/var/lib/nfs/statd/sm.bak`. It's so nice to finally resolve this error message!

Comment: Had the same issue on OpenSUSE 15.3, same fix, thank you @JeffSchaller I can confirm this is still very relevant with the latest versions of `rpc-statd-notify.service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to edit the file

```
/var/lib/nfs/sm.bak
```